# How can I create a dynamic image source with MVC3 and Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view that attempts to build a table off of the passed in Model.  I'd like to generate an image with a source that is changed based on the iteration of a loop but can't seem to get it to work.  I can do this in JQuery but I would like to do it with razor.  I have the following table body:

```
<tbody>
@{for (var ix = 0; ix <= Model.Value.Count - 1; ix++)
{
    <tr>  
    <td style="width: 10%"><img src="http://gmap.com/marker" + @ix + 1 + ".png" /></td>
    <td style="width: 75%">@Model("fullname")</td>
    </tr>
}
<tbody>
```

That first TD is the problem area.  I attempted it but... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is razor you do not need to add the rendered output to your url.  Try this:

```
@{for (var ix = 0; ix <= Model.Value.Count - 1; ix++)
{
    <tr>  
    <td style="width: 10%"><img src="http://gmap.com/marker@(ix + 1).png" /></td>
    <td style="width: 75%">@Model("fullname")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I haven't tested it but I believe it will fix your issue.